# values from c# code behind and pass it to javascript on design page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am working on google geomap and mark some locations , for those locations I am fetching values from database in codebehind

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = this.GetData("SELECT
WaterLevelUS,WaterLevelDS,Alert_Upstream,Alert_Downstream,
Warning_Upstream,Warning_Downstream,DangerUpstream,DangerDownstream 
FROM sgwebdb.stations where StationType='Sluice Station'");
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    sluice_waterlevelus.Value = dt.Rows[i]["WaterLevelUS"].ToString();
    sluice_waterlevelds.Value = dt.Rows[i]["WaterLevelDS"].ToString();
    sluice_alertup.Value = dt.Rows[i]["Alert_Upstream"].ToString();
    sluice_alertdown.Value = dt.Rows[i]["Alert_Downstream"].ToString();
    sluice_warnup.Value = dt.Rows[i]["Warning_Upstream"].ToString();
    sluice_warndown.Value = dt.Rows[i]["Warning_Downstream"].ToString();
    sluice_dangerup.Value = dt.Rows[i]["DangerUpstream"].ToString();
    sluice_dangerdown.Value = dt.Rows[i]["DangerDownstream"].ToString();
}
```

This will give us 48 locations values ,means 48 rows from database.Accordeing to these values we need to change the colour of geomap location mark .we are passing these values to aspx page by hidden field.
Aspx page javascript code for passing values in hidden field for color change of geomap mark

```
if(data.type=='Sluice Station') 
{
    var Sluice_WaterLvlUpValue = $get('<%= sluice_waterlevelus.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue = $get('<%= sluice_waterlevelds.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_AlertUpValue = $get('<%= sluice_alertup.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_AlertDwValue = $get('<%= sluice_alertdown.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_WarnUpValue = $get('<%= sluice_warnup.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_WarnDwValue = $get('<%= sluice_warndown.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_DangerUpValue = $get('<%= sluice_dangerup.ClientID %>').value;
    var Sluice_DangerDwValue = $get('<%= sluice_dangerdown.ClientID %>').value;

    if ((Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue >= Sluice_AlertDwValue && Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue <
    Sluice_WarnDwValue)  || (Sluice_WaterLvlUpValue >= Sluice_AlertUpValue && 
    Sluice_WaterLvlUpValue < Sluice_WarnUpValue)) 
    {
        var icon = "";            
        switch (data.Notype) {               
            case "No status":
                icon = "green";
                break;
        }
    }
    //else if ((data.SensorDown >= DwmidValue && data.SensorDown <= DwmaxValue) || (data.SensorUp >= UpmidValue && data.SensorUp <= UpmaxValue))
    else if ((Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue >= Sluice_WarnDwValue && Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue < 
    Sluice_DangerDwValue) || (Sluice_WaterLvlUpValue >= Sluice_WarnUpValue && 
    Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue < Sluice_DangerUpValue))
    {
        var icon = "";            
        switch (data.Notype) {               
            case "No status":
                icon = "orange";
                break;
        }
    }
    //  else if ((data.SensorDown >= DwmaxValue) || (data.SensorUp >= UpmaxValue))
    else if ((Sluice_WaterLvlDwValue >= Sluice_DangerDwValue) || (Sluice_WaterLvlUpValue
     >= Sluice_DangerUpValue))
    {
        var icon = "";            
        switch (data.Notype) {               
            case "No status":
                icon = "red";
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var icon = "";            
        switch (data.Notype) {               
            case "No status":
                icon = "blue";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

now we need to pass the values from code behind for each station then compare values and give colour to location. But I am not  understanding for each row from .cs page how to pass value to aspx in a loop and change the colour of all 48 location according to their values. Please help.